example of non-strict initial object
Is there a simple example of a category C and a non-strict initial object in C?
Positive examples and the definition of strict initial objects are provided here.
It appears that initial objects in the categories I usually consider (Sets, various kinds of Graphs, etc.) are always strict...
pointed sets
Based on Jochen's comment about pointed sets (which also appear in my context), I summarize my understanding for future reference.

Objects are pairs $(X,x)$ of a set $X$ and an $x\in X$
Morphisms $f:(X,x)\rightarrow (Y,y)$ are maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ satisfying $f(x)=y$
Initial objects are of the form $(\{0\},0)$.
These initial objects $(\{0\},0)$ are not strict since there are always morphisms: $f:(\{1,2\},{1})\rightarrow (\{0\},0)$ that are not injective (and which are therefore also not isomorphic).


$K$-vector spaces and linear maps or pointed sets and base point preserving maps are two examples where the initial objects are not strict.

thanks! I included a summary of an example for future reference

Terminal objects in the categories you mention are not strict, so you can take the opposite of any of your examples to get an example of a non-strict initial object.

I guess it should work for a lot of grothendieck constructions and slice (or coslice not sure) categories in addition for the already stated examples

@Jochen I may be mistaken but how is $0$ not strict in the category of vector spaces? If you replace by unital $k$ algebra it could work

The definition of a strict initial object $o$ is that $o$ is initial and every morphism $X\to o$ is an isomorphism.

Oh yes my bad :)

$\mathbb{Z}$ in the category of unital rings is a non-strict initial object.

I have another good examples (in addition of the two others):
Take any category $\mathcal{C}$ and $X \in \mathcal{C}$ such that there exists an object $Z$ and a invertible morphism $\phi:Z \to X$ invertible on the right (with right inverse $\psi$) but not on the left(for instance vector spaces + surjective linear morphism (but not injective) or simply the constant map $\{0,1\} \to \{0\}$ which will give you pointed sets).
Consider the cosclice category $X/\mathcal{C}$ which:

Objects are pairs $(f,Y)$ where $f:X \to Y$ is an arrow
Morphisms $g:(f,Y) \to (f',Y')$ are morphisms $g:Y \to Y'$ such that $gf = f'$.

The initial object of this category is $(1_X,X)$ and the morphism induced by $h$ which is $\phi:(\psi,Z) \to (1_X,X)$ which is well defined since $\phi \psi = 1_X$. If it also had a left inverse, one would have $\psi':(1_X,X) \to (\psi,Z)$ such that $\psi = \psi'$ and $\psi \phi = 1_Z$ which is definitely false.
Following this example, with vector spaces,$X=k$ and $Z = k^2$ we would get an equivalent of pointed sets for vector spaces

One class that yields plentiful counterexamples are categories with a zero object, that is an object that is both terminal and initial (where the category has at least one object not isomorphic to said object): This subsumes your example, the category of pointed sets ($(\{0\}, 0)$ is a zero object), the category of pointed topological spaces (dito), the category of groups (the trivial group $\{1\}$ is a zero object), and all categories of modules over a (non-trivial) ring (the trivial module is a zero object).

The simplest example is the category with two objects $0$, $1$, and three non-identity morphisms $s\colon 0\to 1$, $r\colon 1\to 0$, and $e\colon 1\to 1$ satisfying $s\circ r=e$. It is universal in the sense that faithful functors out of this category preserving initial objects give all other examples.
The initial object of a coslice category over an object $X$ is not strict if and only if $X$ is the image of $0$ of a faithful functor out of that category.

If all morphisms into an object $0$ are isomorphisms, then composition with a morphisms $X\to 0$ composition is a bijection between morphisms $X\to 0$ and morphisms $0\to 0$.
If there are no non-identity morphisms $0\to 0$, then $0$ is subterminal, i.e. there is at most one morphism to $0$ from every other object.
Thus an initial object is not strict if it is not subterminal.If the category has a terminal object, then subterminal objects are precisely subobjects of the terminal object. In that case an initial object is not strict if its morphism into the terminal object is not a monomorphism.

The category of models of any algebraic theory has initial object with underlying set that of the constant terms of the theory.
The set of functions with a given domain valued in the set of constant terms is in bijection with the set of homomorphisms out of the free structure on the domain.
Thus the initial object is subterminal only if the theory has no constant terms, equivalently, no constants.
Conversely, if the theory has no constant terms, equivalently, no constants, the initial object is strict.

The Kleisli category of the $R^{R^{(-)}}$ monad is an example, where $0$ is initial but not necessarily strict (take $R$ to be something other than $0$).
